# how to check height and width image in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

how to check height and width image in javascript ?

my code is :

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod('allowdimensions', function (value, element, params) {
    if (element.files.length < 1) {
        // No files selected
        return true;
    }
    if (!element.files || !element.files[0].size) {
        // This browser doesn't support the HTML5 API
        return true;
    }
    var minWidth = parseInt(params['minwidth'], 10);
    var maxWidth = parseInt(params['maxwidth'], 10);
    var minHeight = parseInt(params['minheight'], 10);
    var maxHeight = parseInt(params['maxheight'], 10);
    var image = {
        width: 0,
        height: 0
    };
    var reader = new FileReader();
    var img = new Image();
    reader.addEventListener("load", function () {
        img.src = reader.result;
    }, false);

    reader.readAsDataURL(element.files[0]);

    return image.width >= minWidth &&
        image.width <= maxWidth &&
        image.height >= minHeight &&
        image.height <= maxHeight;
});
```

`image.width` and `image.height` always is `0`; To read the image a delay occurs.I do not know how to read the image before return output.

Answer (score 1):

try like this .

```
reader.onload = function (e)
{
image.src = e.target.result;

image.onload = function ()
{
      // access image size here 
      if (this.width < 100 && this.height < 100)
      {
       // alert("To Small Image or your message"); 
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm slightly confused by exactly what you're trying to do here. But try this out: https://jsfiddle.net/3dqnc1wa/1/

jQuery:

```
$("document").ready(function() {
  var imageWidth = $("img").width();
  var imageHeight = $("img").height();
  $("#dims").html("Width: " + imageWidth + " x Height: " + imageHeight)
  if(imageWidth >= 400 && imageHeight >= 200) {
    $("#test").html("It's equal to or wider than 400px and equal to or higher than 200px");
  } else if(imageWidth <= 399 && imageHeight <= 199) {
    $("#test").html("It's smaller than or equal to 399px wide and shorter than of equal to 199px");
  }
;});
```

HTML:

```
<img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
<div id="dims">
</div>
<div id="test">
</div>
```

I've used `.width()` and `.height()` and stored them in variables (`imageWidth` / `imageHeight`) then checked them with some conditionals.

Answer (score 0):

Punit Answer is correct. But if you are using jQuery you can use this:

```
$('#image_id').load(function(){
    var Img_Width = $(this).width();
    var Img_Height = $(this).height();
});
```

You are getting 0 width and height because the image might not be yet loaded in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a small onload function for img , to get the image width and height , you could then manipulate it accordingly.

```
var reader  = new FileReader();
  var img = new Image();

  reader.addEventListener("load", function () {
    preview.src = reader.result;
    img.src=reader.result;
  }, false);

    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  img.onload = function() {
  //alert(this.width + 'x' + this.height);
  image.width=this.width;
  image.height=this.height;
}
```

here this. width is the width of the image and this.height is the height .
AFter u get the height and width of the image store it in image json and compare them with the maxHeight and maxWidth ,minHeight and minWidth.

here is the fiddle 
https://jsfiddle.net/AnonymousKB07/kn0h5tm2/3/
Hope this helps.

Comment: actually he is using var reader  = new FileReader();
  var img = new Image();  that is why ,. . .